# Coroutine error when using threading with python, RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'time_messege' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, discord, artificial-intelligence

They know how to fix these 2 ** coroutine errors when using threading with python ** :

```
C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py:870: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'time_messege' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

From this function in a main script I assemble the thread

```py
    async def on_ready(self) -> None:

        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

        x = threading.Thread(target=time_messege) #Creo un thread independiente del main_thread
        x.start()
```

Import this... :

```py
from core.modules.greetings import time_messege
import threading
import asyncio
```

But it still doesn't work:

```py
import time, random, discord
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio


async def time_messege():

    alarmtime = "09:59"
    channel = bot.get_channel("814238156396298310")

    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            random_num = random.randint(1, 4)

            if answer_num == 1:
                await greeting_channel.send(f"""AA""")
            if answer_num == 2:
                await greeting_channel.send(f"""A""")
            if answer_num == 3:
                await greeting_channel.send(f"""B""")
            elif answer_num == 4:
                await greeting_channel.send(f"""c""")

            time.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            time.sleep(10)
```

The truth is that I no longer understand why that error appears, I hope you can help me with these 2 errors.

Answer (score 1):

`time_message` is an async function but when you start it, you aren't awaiting it.
However I do not recommend using threading in your bot. time.sleep will lead to [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean) in your bot.

discord.py has its own native extension for making [task loops](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks). You should check this out, as it is made to work with an asynchronous environment.